# Find the Nth number whose only prime factors are 2, 3, 5, and/or 7 (humble numbers)

Tags: code-golf, primes

First post here! I recently participated in a small friendly competition and this was one of the questions:

---

A positive integer whose only prime factors are 2, 3, 5 or 7 is called a [humble number](https://oeis.org/A002473).

The first 20 humble numbers are:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 16, 18, 20, 21, 24, 25, 27
```

Write a program of function that when given a positive integer N, prints or returns the Nth humble number.

**Examples**

```
1 -> 1
11 -> 12
22 -> 30
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest answer in bytes wins. I'm interested in seeing solutions that run in O(N) but this is not a requirement.

Comment: @Calvin'sHobbies: I thought that too, but the very last line was what made me wonder if this post was misplaced.

Comment: `1` doesn't contain either one of the factors `2,3,5,7`.

Comment: @mroman the linked OEIS page describes them less ambiguously as "`Numbers whose prime divisors are all <= 7`".

Comment: @mroman - 1 doesn't contain any prime factors that aren't 2, 3, 5, or 7. That it doesn't contain those four either isn't relevant.